# Fatal exception in interrupt when booting Linux 3.3.7 on BeagleBoard

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel

I have tried to implement a new scheduling algorithm in Linux Kernel 3.3.7 and boot it on the BeagleBoard. However, it throws errors like "Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt". I have enabled low level debugs functions and the debug infos are as follows:

```
[    0.000000] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[    0.000000] WARNING: at kernel/lockdep.c:2592 do_vfp+0x8/0x20()
[    0.000000] Modules linked in:
[    0.000000] [<c001c2ec>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0x130) from [<c0045afc>] (warn_slow)
[    0.000000] [<c0045afc>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x4c/0x64) from [<c0045b30>] (warn_)
[    0.000000] [<c0045b30>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x1c/0x24) from [<c000f328>] (do_vfp+)
[    0.000000] ---[ end trace 1b75b31a2719ed1c ]---
[    0.000000] Error before arm_notify_die- GDEM-UPM 
[    0.000000] Internal error: Oops - undefined instruction: 0 [#1] SMP
[    0.000000] Modules linked in:
[    0.000000] CPU: 0    Tainted: G        W     (3.3.0-rc7-00008-g8bd3d32-dirty #5)
[    0.000000] PC is at update_curr+0x4/0x5d0
[    0.000000] LR is at task_tick_fair+0x3c/0x154
[    0.000000] pc : [<c0079ac0>]    lr : [<c007a274>]    psr: 800001d3
[    0.000000] sp : c0699e2c  ip : c0698000  fp : c0699ea4
[    0.000000] r10: 00000000  r9 : c0723748  r8 : 00000000
[    0.000000] r7 : 00000000  r6 : c06b4630  r5 : c0e083e8  r4 : c0e08380
[    0.000000] r3 : c007a238  r2 : c06b2108  r1 : c06b4668  r0 : c0e083e8
[    0.000000] Flags: Nzcv  IRQs off  FIQs off  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment kernel
[    0.000000] Control: 10c5387d  Table: 80004019  DAC: 00000017
[    0.000000] Process swapper/0 (pid: 0, stack limit = 0xc06982f8)
[    0.000000] Stack: (0xc0699e2c to 0xc069a000)
[    0.000000] 9e20:                            c0e08380 c0e083e8 c06b4630 00000000 00
[    0.000000] 9e40: c0723748 00000000 c0699ea4 c007a274 00000002 c06b4630 00000000 00
[    0.000000] 9e60: c0723748 c06b4668 600001d3 c0e08380 00000000 c06b4630 00000000 00
[    0.000000] 9e80: c0723748 00000000 c0699ea4 c00755f0 c0698000 c06b4630 00000000 00
[    0.000000] 9ea0: c072375c c0055288 00000000 00000000 c069a144 00000000 00000000 c0
[    0.000000] 9ec0: c06b7bc0 c069e954 c06b7b40 c002713c 00000000 c008b084 00000000 cc
[    0.000000] 9ee0: 00000000 c06b7bc0 c069e954 0000005f c002713c 00000000 00000000 c0
[    0.000000] 9f00: 00000000 c00a449c 411fc083 00000000 600001d3 c069e900 c069e954 c0
[    0.000000] 9f20: c069e954 c06b7bc0 0000005f 00000000 411fc083 00000000 00000000 c8
[    0.000000] 9f40: c069e900 c069e954 00000001 c00a6b9c c06b2108 c06960e0 c0698000 c0
[    0.000000] 9f60: 000001da c00155f8 fa200000 c0699f90 ffffffff c0699fc4 80004059 cc
[    0.000000] 9f80: c06b4630 c06486d4 20000153 c0483e24 00000000 00000001 01ffffff c4
[    0.000000] 9fa0: 600001d3 c067925c c0e03980 c06b5e14 80004059 411fc083 00000000 00
[    0.000000] 9fc0: 00000001 c0699fd8 00000001 c06486d4 20000153 ffffffff c06481c4 00
[    0.000000] 9fe0: 00000000 c067925c 10c53c7d c06b0cc0 c067922c 80008044 00000000 00
[    0.000000] unwind: Unhandled instruction c9
[    0.000000] Code: c0491260 c0491264 c04911b4 e92d4ff0 (ed2d8b02) 
[    0.000000] ---[ end trace 1b75b31a2719ed1d ]---
[    0.000000] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt`
```

Any idea where comes the error? 
Is there any debug tool(maybe KGDB) that can be used to debug the kernel before the it is booted?

Thx!

Comment: Well, you can start by reading the KP and looking at the `update_curr` function.

Comment: Thanks! How do you know the problem can be from the function update_curr? I have made some modifications in the update_curr function. And I wonder if there is any way or tool to detect which line(s) of code cause the kernel panic. I hope to find some tool that can help me to effectively find the problem.

Comment: The KP tells you everything you need to know. You can compile the kernel with debugging symbols and run `gdb` on vmlinux. Feed it the address and it'll give you the file and line.

Comment: Thanks! I have just found that by run gdb on vmlinux and then command l *update_curr+0x4 can lead to the line.

Answer (score 0):

The best and really the only way you should debug the boot process is to use the **serial debug port** on your beagleboard. It is not so obvious, but you have to physically attach wires from an FTDI cable to headers on the beagleboard. [Page 17 of this guide](https://github.com/beagleboard/beagleboard-x15/blob/master/BeagleBoard-X15_Quick-Start-Guide.pdf) indicates that this is done on UART3 of the beagleboard. This is also the easiest way to interrupt the boot process and enter the Uboot command prompt.

I've found that using minicom is the best linux program see serial debug information from a serial port in the terminal. Please let me know if you have anymore questions.